# get attribute with jQuery complication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get images alt attribute which is inside another tag but the thing is I have similar images all over the place the only way I can access those is by using `this` keyword.

```
jQuery(".content p").mouseenter(function () {
    var temp = jQuery(this+' img').attr('alt');
    jQuery(this).append("<span>shit men</span>");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <p><img src="sites/all/themes/nexus/images/image-frame.png " alt="Product1"></p>
  <p><img src="sites/all/themes/nexus/images/image-frame.png " alt="Product2"></p>
</div>
```

By using `this` I can only access `<p>` tag but I want to access `<img>` tag through `this` keyword and the above code is not working. My question is it possible to concatenate tags to `this` e.g `this+' img'` ?

Comment: `$('img', this).attr('alt')`

Comment: adeneo -> well u should write this in the answer, not in the comment. but thanks it works.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you'll need to get the `IMG` inside selected element, so just find it.

```
jQuery(".content p").mouseenter(function () {
    var temp = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    jQuery(this).append("<span>shit men</span>");
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, not just code. Clearly the OP is a beginner, so the more you explain, the more helpful your answer will be.

Comment: ya sorry i started JQuery 2 Days ago. am new but thanks adaneo answered the question with short line of code. but not on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img', this).attr('alt');  // source from adeneo
```